# Hibernate Criteria having a group of conditions in OR, picked from a list

Tags: hibernate, orm

I have an attribute "salePointId" in SellingRate entity. Now I want to create a Criteria such that it fetches objects with salePointId in list.

```
    List<Integer> salePointIds; // some list coming from code above
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(SellingRate.class)
            .add(Restrictions.ge("endDate", date))
            .add(Restrictions.le("startDate", date));
    for (int id: salePointIds) {
        // what should be written here
        // to get an OR of restrictions on id
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Restriocion.disjunction() can be used for it.

```
List<Integer> salePointIds; // some list coming from code above
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(SellingRate.class)
        .add(Restrictions.ge("endDate", date))
        .add(Restrictions.le("startDate", date));
Disjunction conditionsInOR = Restrictions.disjunction();
for (int id: salePointIds) {
    conditionsInOR.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
}
criteria.add(conditionsInOR);
```

Alternative :

```
Critera criteria = session.createCriteria(SellingRate.class)
        .add(Restrictions.ge("endDate", date)
        .add(Restrictions.le("startDate", date)
        .add(Property.forName("id").in(list.toArray())
```